# Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Getting below mentioned error while while using `html_editor_enhanced` this plugin in my flutter web app project, my flutter doctor has no issue, I tried adding `flutter_colorpicker` latest version in `pubspec.yaml` but still that didn't helped.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
    /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.4.0/lib/src/hsv_picker.dart:731:29: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the
    parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'.
     - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
     - 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
        super.addAllowedPointer(event);
                                ^
    Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             55.0s
    Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: Getting this error when simply trying to build an app... not making use of the picker at all...